# Variable length colon seperated string regex validation

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex to validate and extract the values from a colon separated string that can have 1-4 values. I have found example where there are a fixed number of variables and tried to use this but it only picks up the first and last values, I need to extract all of them. The current regex is also including the : in the match, I simply want the value if possible

I am currently using this;

```
^([01ab])+(\:[01ab])*
```

but it only pulls the first and last values, not those in between if they exist.

Valid values;

```
0

0:a

0:a:1

0:1:a:b
```

Not valid

```
0:a:

0:a:1:b:
```

Comment: Can't you use a simple two step approach: `if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[01ab](?::[01ab])*$")) { result = text.Split(':');  }`?

Comment: What about `0::a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a two-step approach: validate the format with the regex and then split the string with `:` if it qualifies:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[01ab](?::[01ab])*$")) 
{
    result = text.Split(':');
}
```

The `^[01ab](?::[01ab])*$` regex matches start of a string with `^`, a `0`, `1`, `a` or `b`, and then 0 or more repetitions of `:` followed with  a `0`, `1`, `a` or `b` and then end of string (`$`).

If you want to play with the regex a bit you will see that C# allows you to access all capture group values via `CaptureCollection`:

```
var text = "0:1:a:b";
var results = Regex.Match(text, @"^(?:([01ab])(?::\b|$))+$")?
        .Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results)); // => 0, 1, a, b
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/xs3NZH) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%5b01ab%5d%29%28%3f%3a%3a%5cb%7c%5cr%3f%24%29%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=0%0d%0a0%3aa%0d%0a0%3aa%3a1%0d%0a0%3a1%3aa%3ab%0d%0a%0d%0a0%3aa%3a%0d%0a0%3aa%3a1%3ab%3a&o=m).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([01ab])(?::\b|$))+`  - 1 or more repetitions of:

  - `([01ab])` - Group 1: `0`, `1`, `a` or `b`
  - `(?::\b|$)` - either `:` followed with a letter, digit (`\b` will also allow  `_` to follow, but it is missing in the pattern) or end of string
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

A not using regex approach (and why would you use regex unless you really have to) is this:

```
bool Validate(string s)
{
    string[] valid = {"0", "1", "a", "b"};
    var splitArray = s.Split(':');

    if (splitArray.Length < 1 || splitArray.Length > 4)
          return false;

    return splitArray.All(a => valid.Contains(a));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is more efficient to use a string method than regex.  So try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = { "0", "0:a", "0:a:1", "0:1:a:b", "Not valid", "0:a:", "0:a:1:b:" };

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                string[] splitArray = input.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

                if (splitArray.Length < 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Input: '{0}' Not Valid", input);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Input: '{0}' First Value : '{1}', Last Value : '{2}'", input, splitArray[0], splitArray[splitArray.Length - 1]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't check the entries are valid i.e one of 01a or b, it doesn't check there are not > 4 values, it returns invalid when < 2 which should be < 1 and because you remove entry entries, won't detect when the string ends in a ":".   And you have an unecessary ToArray on something that already returns an array.

Comment: I'm checking length so < 2 is correct.  The OP didn't specify what data is valid or not valid so I did not do any error checking.  Also I used StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to remove any empty entries.

Comment: no the length can be 1 so it needs to be < 1.  The regex indicates that 0 1 a and b are the only valid chars. by removing the empty entries you then fail to validate the specified incorrect "0:a:1:b:" as the last : will be ignored.